# Beamer latex (table not created)

Tags: tables, beamer, allowframebreaks

I am using the following commands:

```
\subsection{Predicting crises}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Predicting crises}


\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25\\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
&  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Out-of-sample}   \\
2001-2003 & 0.1 & 75 & 80.95 & 25.00 & 19.05 & 44.04 \\
2004-2006 & 0.1 & 33.33 & 91.86 & 66.67 & 8.14 & 74.80 \\
2007-2009 & 0.09 & 54.55 & 82.89 & 45.45 & 17.11 & 62.55 \\
2010-2012 & 0.09 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 &  27.59 & 27.59 \\
2013-2015 & 0.09 & 80.00 & 74.36 & 20.00 & 25.64 & 45.64 \\
2016-2018 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 87.21 & 33.33 & 12.79 & 46.12 \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{3-year ahead in- and out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 1yprediction}
    \end{table}




\newpage


\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Actual crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{Missed crises} &
\mcx{Actual non-crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{False alarms}  \\
    \midrule
\addlinespace
2001-2003  & 4   & 3   & 1  & 84  & 68   & 16  \\

2004-2006  & 3   & 1   & 2  & 86  & 79   & 7   \\

2007-2009  & 11  & 6   & 5  & 76  & 63   & 13  \\

2010-2012  & 0   & 0   & 0  & 87  & 63   & 24  \\

2013-2015  & 10  & 8   & 2  & 78  & 58   & 20  \\

2016-2018  & 3   & 2   & 1  & 86  & 75   & 11  \\
\midrule 
Total      & 31  & 20  & 11 & 497 & 406  & 91  \\
\midrule 
Percentage & 100\%  & 64.52\%   & 35.48\%  & 100\%   & 81.69\%    & 18.31\%   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{3-year ahead overall out-of-sample performance}
\label{table:ovoutsaperformance}
\end{table}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------















%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2001 & 0.09 & 80.77  & 64.11 & 19.23 & 35.89 & 55.11 \\
1970-2002 & 0.09 & 80.25 & 63.73 & 19.75 & 36.27 & 56.02 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1 & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2004 & 0.09 & 77.78 & 68.22 & 22.22 & 31.78 & 54 \\
1970-2005 & 0.07 & 86.9 & 57.77 & 13.1 & 42.23 & 55.32 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19  & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2007 & 0.07 & 84.52 & 61.41 & 15.48 & 38.59 & 54.06 \\
1970-2008 & 0.07 &  88.30 & 55.96 & 11.70 & 44.04 & 55.74 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89  & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25 \\
1970-2010 & 0.09 & 76.84 & 68.24 & 23.16 & 31.76 & 54.92 \\
1970-2011 & 0.07 & 86.32 & 59.02 & 13.68 & 40.98 & 54.66 \\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2013 & 0.08 & 79.59 & 66.1 & 20.41 & 33.9 & 54.30 \\
1970-2014 & 0.08 & 80.39 & 65.56 & 19.61 & 34.44 & 54.05 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
1970-2016 & 0.09 & 77.36 & 71.24 & 22.64 & 28.76 & 51.39 \\
1970-2017 & 0.09 & 74.53 & 72.47 & 25.47 & 27.53 & 52.99 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead in-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yisprediction}
    \end{table}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage


\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
1970-2000 & 0.1  &  75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2001 & 0.09 & 80.77  & 64.11 & 19.23 & 35.89 & 55.11 \\
1970-2002 & 0.09 & 80.25 & 63.73 & 19.75 & 36.27 & 56.02 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1 & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2004 & 0.09 & 77.78 & 68.22 & 22.22 & 31.78 & 54 \\
1970-2005 & 0.07 & 86.9 & 57.77 & 13.1 & 42.23 & 55.32 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19  & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2007 & 0.07 & 84.52 & 61.41 & 15.48 & 38.59 & 54.06 \\
1970-2008 & 0.07 &  88.30 & 55.96 & 11.70 & 44.04 & 55.74 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89  & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25 \\
1970-2010 & 0.09 & 76.84 & 68.24 & 23.16 & 31.76 & 54.92 \\
1970-2011 & 0.07 & 86.32 & 59.02 & 13.68 & 40.98 & 54.66 \\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2013 & 0.08 & 79.59 & 66.1 & 20.41 & 33.9 & 54.30 \\
1970-2014 & 0.08 & 80.39 & 65.56 & 19.61 & 34.44 & 54.05 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
1970-2016 & 0.09 & 77.36 & 71.24 & 22.64 & 28.76 & 51.39 \\
1970-2017 & 0.09 & 74.53 & 72.47 & 25.47 & 27.53 & 52.99 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead in-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yisprediction}
    \end{table}





%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
2001 & 0.1 & 100 & 82.14 & 0 & 17.86 & 17.85 \\ 
2002 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 73.08 & 33.33 & 26.92 & 60.25 \\ 
2003 & 0.09 & 0 & 83.33 & 0 & 16.67 & 16.67 \\ 
2004 & 0.1 & 0 & 90 & 0 & 10 & 10 \\ 
2005 & 0.09 & 33.33 & 96.3 & 66.67 & 3.7 & 70.37 \\ 
2006 & 0.07 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 & 27.59 & 27.59 \\ 
2007 & 0.09 & 0 & 89.66 & 0 & 10.34 & 10.34 \\ 
2008 & 0.07 & 50 & 100 & 50 & 0 & 50 \\ 
2009 & 0.07 & 100 & 35.71 & 0 & 64.29 & 64.29 \\ 
2010 & 0.09 & 0 & 75.86 & 0 & 24.14 & 24.14 \\ 
2011 & 0.09 & 0 & 75.86 & 0 & 24.14 & 24.14 \\ 
2012 & 0.07 & 0 & 62.07 & 0 & 37.93 & 37.93 \\ 
2013 & 0.09 & 100 & 80.77 & 0 & 19.23 & 19.23 \\ 
2014 & 0.08 & 100 & 64 & 0 & 36 & 36 \\ 
2015 & 0.08 & 66.67 & 59.26 & 33.33 & 40.74 & 74.07 \\ 
2016 & 0.09 & 100 & 86.21 & 0 & 13.79 & 13.79 \\ 
2017 & 0.09 & 0 & 83.33 & 0 & 16.67 & 16.67 \\ 
2018 & 0.09 & 50 & 92.59 & 50 & 7.41  & 57.40 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yosprediction}
    \end{table}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
 \addlinespace
2001 & 0.1 & 100 & 82.14 & 0 & 17.86 & 17.85 \\ 
2002 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 73.08 & 33.33 & 26.92 & 60.25 \\ 
2003 & 0.09 & 0 & 83.33 & 0 & 16.67 & 16.67 \\ 
2004 & 0.1 & 0 & 90 & 0 & 10 & 10 \\ 
2005 & 0.09 & 33.33 & 96.3 & 66.67 & 3.7 & 70.37 \\ 
2006 & 0.07 & 0 & 72.41 & 0 & 27.59 & 27.59 \\ 
2007 & 0.09 & 0 & 89.66 & 0 & 10.34 & 10.34 \\ 
2008 & 0.07 & 50 & 100 & 50 & 0 & 50 \\ 
2009 & 0.07 & 100 & 35.71 & 0 & 64.29 & 64.29 \\ 
2010 & 0.09 & 0 & 75.86 & 0 & 24.14 & 24.14 \\ 
2011 & 0.09 & 0 & 75.86 & 0 & 24.14 & 24.14 \\ 
2012 & 0.07 & 0 & 62.07 & 0 & 37.93 & 37.93 \\ 
2013 & 0.09 & 100 & 80.77 & 0 & 19.23 & 19.23 \\ 
2014 & 0.08 & 100 & 64 & 0 & 36 & 36 \\ 
2015 & 0.08 & 66.67 & 59.26 & 33.33 & 40.74 & 74.07 \\ 
2016 & 0.09 & 100 & 86.21 & 0 & 13.79 & 13.79 \\ 
2017 & 0.09 & 0 & 83.33 & 0 & 16.67 & 16.67 \\ 
2018 & 0.09 & 50 & 92.59 & 50 & 7.41  & 57.40 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yosprediction}
    \end{table}




%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage

\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Actual crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{Missed crises} &
\mcx{Actual non-crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{False alarms}  \\
    \midrule
\addlinespace
2001          & 1             & 1                   & 0             & 28                & 23                  & 5              \\
2002          & 3             & 2                   & 1             & 26                & 19                  & 7              \\
2003          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 30                & 25                  & 5              \\
2004          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 30                & 27                  & 3              \\
2005          & 3             & 1                   & 2             & 27                & 26                  & 1              \\
2006          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 29                & 21                  & 8              \\
2007          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 29                & 26                  & 3              \\
2008          & 10            & 5                   & 5             & 19                & 19                  & 0              \\
2009          & 1             & 1                   & 0             & 28                & 10                  & 18             \\
2010          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 29                & 22                  & 7              \\
2011          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 29                & 22                  & 7              \\
2012          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 29                & 18                  & 11             \\
2013          & 3             & 3                   & 0             & 26                & 21                  & 5              \\
2014          & 4             & 4                   & 0             & 25                & 16                  & 9              \\
2015          & 3             & 2                   & 1             & 27                & 16                  & 11             \\
2016          & 1             & 1                   & 0             & 29                & 25                  & 4              \\
2017          & 0             & 0                   & 0             & 30                & 25                  & 5              \\
2018          & 2             & 1                   & 1             & 27                & 25                  & 2              \\

\midrule 
Total         & 31            & 21                  & 10            & 497               & 386                 & 111            \\

\midrule 

Percentage    & 100\%       & 67.74\%              & 32.26\%         & 100\%            & 77.67\%               & 22.33\%          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx} performance
\caption{1-year ahead overall out-of-sample performance}
\label{table:1yaovoutsaperformance}
\end{table}


\end{frame}
```

The commands creates me just the first three tables and the frame stops. Is something wrong with table's command or the frame is too big?

P.S. I have some text before the tables which I didn't added here.

Comment: (i) your document example is not compilable, (ii) you use my code which I provide you on your previous question, but you not up-vote my answer nor accept it. This means, that answer not fulfill your expectation and consequently you will not use suggested solution!

Comment: I didn't find the way how to up vote the question. And second the code didn't work that well since it doesn't creates all the tables I want. I thing it is something wrong with it, because if I remove the tables a just write the text in the next frame page it works but it doesn't do so if I use this codes. It just creates the first 3 tables and then it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for manually break frame to slides serve command ``framebreak`
- after `\framebreak` command should be empty line
- command `framebreak` has sense to use, if you like to break a frame at point earlier where frame breaks automatically
- content of one slide had not to be bigger than text area of slide, otherwise the breaking mechanism doesn't work well
- some of your tables are quite big, so that can be fit on slide nicely, I reduce font size to `scriptsize` and line spreading to 0.9

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
%----
    \makeatletter
    % arabic numbering of slides in the titles
    % as <frame num>/<slide num> 
    \newcounter{cont}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}%
    {%
    \setcounter{cont}{\beamer@endpageofframe}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
    (\insertcontinuationcount/\arabic{cont})%
    }% end frame title continuation
    \makeatother
%----

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash%
                                     \linespread{0.84}\selectfont}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Predicting crises}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Predicting crises}
    \scriptsize\linespread{0.9}\selectfont
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
1970-2000 & 0.1  & 75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25 \\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
    \midrule
&  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Out-of-sample}   \\
2001-2003 & 0.1  & 75    & 80.95 & 25.00 & 19.05 & 44.04 \\
2004-2006 & 0.1  & 33.33 & 91.86 & 66.67 & 8.14  & 74.80 \\
2007-2009 & 0.09 & 54.55 & 82.89 & 45.45 & 17.11 & 62.55 \\
2010-2012 & 0.09 & 0     & 72.41 & 0     & 27.59 & 27.59 \\
2013-2015 & 0.09 & 80.00 & 74.36 & 20.00 & 25.64 & 45.64 \\
2016-2018 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 87.21 & 33.33 & 12.79 & 46.12 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{3-year ahead in- and out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 1yprediction}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=3.2,
                                          table-align-text-post=false]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Actual crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{Missed crises} &
\mcx{Actual non-crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{False alarms}  \\
    \midrule
2001-2003  & 4   & 3   & 1  & 84  & 68   & 16  \\
2004-2006  & 3   & 1   & 2  & 86  & 79   & 7   \\
2007-2009  & 11  & 6   & 5  & 76  & 63   & 13  \\
2010-2012  & 0   & 0   & 0  & 87  & 63   & 24  \\
2013-2015  & 10  & 8   & 2  & 78  & 58   & 20  \\
2016-2018  & 3   & 2   & 1  & 86  & 75   & 11  \\
\midrule
Total      & 31  & 20  & 11 & 497 & 406  & 91  \\
\midrule
Percentage & 100\%  & 64.52\%   & 35.48\%  & 100\%   & 81.69\%    & 18.31\%   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{3-year ahead overall out-of-sample performance}
\label{table:ovoutsaperformance}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
1970-2000 & 0.1  & 75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2001 & 0.09 & 80.77 & 64.11 & 19.23 & 35.89 & 55.11 \\
1970-2002 & 0.09 & 80.25 & 63.73 & 19.75 & 36.27 & 56.02 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2004 & 0.09 & 77.78 & 68.22 & 22.22 & 31.78 & 54 \\
1970-2005 & 0.07 & 86.9  & 57.77 & 13.1  & 42.23 & 55.32 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2007 & 0.07 & 84.52 & 61.41 & 15.48 & 38.59 & 54.06 \\
1970-2008 & 0.07 & 88.30 & 55.96 & 11.70 & 44.04 & 55.74 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25 \\
1970-2010 & 0.09 & 76.84 & 68.24 & 23.16 & 31.76 & 54.92 \\
1970-2011 & 0.07 & 86.32 & 59.02 & 13.68 & 40.98 & 54.66 \\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2013 & 0.08 & 79.59 & 66.1  & 20.41 & 33.9  & 54.30 \\
1970-2014 & 0.08 & 80.39 & 65.56 & 19.61 & 34.44 & 54.05 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
1970-2016 & 0.09 & 77.36 & 71.24 & 22.64 & 28.76 & 51.39 \\
1970-2017 & 0.09 & 74.53 & 72.47 & 25.47 & 27.53 & 52.99 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead in-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yisprediction}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
1970-2000 & 0.1  & 75.32 & 67.24 & 24.68 & 32.76 & 57.43 \\
1970-2001 & 0.09 & 80.77 & 64.11 & 19.23 & 35.89 & 55.11 \\
1970-2002 & 0.09 & 80.25 & 63.73 & 19.75 & 36.27 & 56.02 \\
1970-2003 & 0.1  & 74.07 & 71.05 & 25.93 & 28.95 & 54.87 \\
1970-2004 & 0.09 & 77.78 & 68.22 & 22.22 & 31.78 & 54    \\
1970-2005 & 0.07 & 86.9  & 57.77 & 13.1  & 42.23 & 55.32 \\
1970-2006 & 0.09 & 76.19 & 68.81 & 23.81 & 31.19 & 54.99 \\
1970-2007 & 0.07 & 84.52 & 61.41 & 15.48 & 38.59 & 54.06 \\
1970-2008 & 0.07 & 88.30 & 55.96 & 11.70 & 44.04 & 55.74 \\
1970-2009 & 0.09 & 77.89 & 66.86 & 22.11 & 33.14 & 55.25 \\
1970-2010 & 0.09 & 76.84 & 68.24 & 23.16 & 31.76 & 54.92 \\
1970-2011 & 0.07 & 86.32 & 59.02 & 13.68 & 40.98 & 54.66 \\
1970-2012 & 0.09 & 73.68 & 70.85 & 26.32 & 29.15 & 55.46 \\
1970-2013 & 0.08 & 79.59 & 66.1  & 20.41 & 33.9  & 54.30 \\
1970-2014 & 0.08 & 80.39 & 65.56 & 19.61 & 34.44 & 54.05 \\
1970-2015 & 0.09 & 77.14 & 70.45 & 22.86 & 29.55 & 52.40 \\
1970-2016 & 0.09 & 77.36 & 71.24 & 22.64 & 28.76 & 51.39 \\
1970-2017 & 0.09 & 74.53 & 72.47 & 25.47 & 27.53 & 52.99 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead in-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yisprediction}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
2001 & 0.1  & 100   & 82.14 & 0     & 17.86 & 17.85 \\
2002 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 73.08 & 33.33 & 26.92 & 60.25 \\
2003 & 0.09 & 0     & 83.33 & 0     & 16.67 & 16.67 \\
2004 & 0.1  & 0     & 90    & 0     & 10    & 10    \\
2005 & 0.09 & 33.33 & 96.3  & 66.67 & 3.7   & 70.37 \\
2006 & 0.07 & 0     & 72.41 & 0     & 27.59 & 27.59 \\
2007 & 0.09 & 0     & 89.66 & 0     & 10.34 & 10.34 \\
2008 & 0.07 & 50    & 100   & 50    & 0     & 50    \\
2009 & 0.07 & 100   & 35.71 & 0     & 64.29 & 64.29 \\
2010 & 0.09 & 0     & 75.86 & 0     & 24.14 & 24.14 \\
2011 & 0.09 & 0     & 75.86 & 0     & 24.14 & 24.14 \\
2012 & 0.07 & 0     & 62.07 & 0     & 37.93 & 37.93 \\
2013 & 0.09 & 100   & 80.77 & 0     & 19.23 & 19.23 \\
2014 & 0.08 & 100   & 64    & 0     & 36    & 36    \\
2015 & 0.08 & 66.67 & 59.26 & 33.33 & 40.74 & 74.07 \\
2016 & 0.09 & 100   & 86.21 & 0     & 13.79 & 13.79 \\
2017 & 0.09 & 0     & 83.33 & 0     & 16.67 & 16.67 \\
2018 & 0.09 & 50    & 92.59 & 50    & 7.41  & 57.40 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yosprediction}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Probability cutoff value} &
\mcx{Crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} &
\mcx{Missed crises (\%)} &
\mcx{False alarm (\%)} &
\mcx{TME}  \\
    \midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{In-sample}   \\
2001 & 0.1 & 100    & 82.14 & 0     & 17.86 & 17.85 \\
2002 & 0.09 & 66.67 & 73.08 & 33.33 & 26.92 & 60.25 \\
2003 & 0.09 & 0     & 83.33 & 0     & 16.67 & 16.67 \\
2004 & 0.1 & 0      & 90    & 0     & 10    & 10    \\
2005 & 0.09 & 33.33 & 96.3  & 66.67 & 3.7   & 70.37 \\
2006 & 0.07 & 0     & 72.41 & 0     & 27.59 & 27.59 \\
2007 & 0.09 & 0     & 89.66 & 0     & 10.34 & 10.34 \\
2008 & 0.07 & 50    & 100   & 50    & 0     & 50    \\
2009 & 0.07 & 100   & 35.71 & 0     & 64.29 & 64.29 \\
2010 & 0.09 & 0     & 75.86 & 0     & 24.14 & 24.14 \\
2011 & 0.09 & 0     & 75.86 & 0     & 24.14 & 24.14 \\
2012 & 0.07 & 0     & 62.07 & 0     & 37.93 & 37.93 \\
2013 & 0.09 & 100   & 80.77 & 0     & 19.23 & 19.23 \\
2014 & 0.08 & 100   & 64    & 0     & 36    & 36    \\
2015 & 0.08 & 66.67 & 59.26 & 33.33 & 40.74 & 74.07 \\
2016 & 0.09 & 100   & 86.21 & 0     & 13.79 & 13.79 \\
2017 & 0.09 & 0     & 83.33 & 0     & 16.67 & 16.67 \\
2018 & 0.09 & 50    & 92.59 & 50    & 7.41  & 57.40 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{1-year ahead out-of-sample prediction}
\label{table: 3yosprediction}
    \end{table}
%\framebreak

    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=3.2,
                                          table-align-text-post=false]} @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Sample window} &
\mcx{Actual crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{Missed crises} &
\mcx{Actual non-crises} &
\mcx{Correctly predicted} &
\mcx{False alarms}  \\
    \midrule
2001    & 1     & 1     & 0     & 28    & 23    & 5     \\
2002    & 3     & 2     & 1     & 26    & 19    & 7     \\
2003    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 30    & 25    & 5     \\
2004    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 30    & 27    & 3     \\
2005    & 3     & 1     & 2     & 27    & 26    & 1     \\
2006    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 29    & 21    & 8     \\
2007    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 29    & 26    & 3     \\
2008    & 10    & 5     & 5     & 19    & 19    & 0     \\
2009    & 1     & 1     & 0     & 28    & 10    & 18    \\
2010    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 29    & 22    & 7     \\
2011    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 29    & 22    & 7     \\
2012    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 29    & 18    & 11    \\
2013    & 3     & 3     & 0     & 26    & 21    & 5     \\
2014    & 4     & 4     & 0     & 25    & 16    & 9     \\
2015    & 3     & 2     & 1     & 27    & 16    & 11    \\
2016    & 1     & 1     & 0     & 29    & 25    & 4     \\
2017    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 30    & 25    & 5     \\
2018    & 2     & 1     & 1     & 27    & 25    & 2     \\
\midrule
Total   & 31    & 21    & 10    & 497   & 386   & 111   \\
    \midrule
Percentage  & 100\% & 67.74\%   & 32.26\%   & 100\% & 77.67\%   & 22.33\%   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\caption{1-year ahead overall out-of-sample performance}
\label{table:1yaovoutsaperformance}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```